# Pushing first character at last and returning the string

Tags: javascript

I was trying to find out a way where I can push the first character to the last and return the rest of the string.
suppose like reverse("aeiou") should be able to return 
eioua
iouae
ouaei
uaeio

```js
function strR(str){
var a = str.split('');
var tmp =[];
a.map (item => {tmp.unshift(item)
console.log(tmp);
})

}
strR("aeiou")
```

aeiou

I tried a lot seems not working . If anyone can help me would be really appreciated.

Comment: post the code you tried

Comment: Added what I have tried .

Comment: In your code, you can see that unshift will insert the element at the start of `tmp` array but instead what you want is to put the starting element at the last.

Answer (score 2):

```js
let bla = "aeiou";
for (let i = 0; i < bla.length; i++) {
  bla = bla.slice(1) + bla[0];
  console.log(bla);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Try this! Alert data can print out wherever

```js
  function myFunction() {
    var str = "aeiou";
    var count = str.length;
    for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) { 
      var res = str.substring(0, 1);
      var result = str.slice(1); 
      var data = result + res;
      str = data;
      alert(data);
    }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use substr to remove the first character and charAt to add it to the end.

```
   var string = 'aeiou'
   i=0 
   while (i < 10) {
      string = string.substr(1) + string.charAt(0);
      console.log(string);
      i++;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for this.

```js
let input = "aeiou";
let chunk = input.split("");
let output = [];

for(let i=0; i<chunk.length;i++){
  let last = chunk.shift();
  chunk.push(last);
  output.push(chunk.toString().replace(/,/g, ''));
}

console.log("Output", output.toString());
```

Comment: Thanks for giving your effort to help me out . But I think problem statement is not solved by this. What I wanted is to return :eioua
iouae
ouaei
uaeio
aeiou

Comment: @nabanita Answer Updated

Answer (score 1):

there is a short and easier way for do that:

```
function FirstToEnd (str){
     return str.substr(1) + str[0]
}
```

and for result all possible data:

```
function FirstToEndAllPossible(str) {
    let result = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        str = str.substr(1) + str[0];
        result.push(str);
    }
    return result;
}
```

good luck :)

Comment: It will not print the sequence rather it will print the final output :) 
aeiou",
  "eioua",
  "iouae",
  "ouaei",
  "uaeio"

Comment: the post is updated. check please and see if it helps send upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one liner using `Array.from` and `slice` methods.

```js
const str = "aeiou";

const str_arr = Array.from(
  new Array(str.length),
  (_, i) => `${str.slice(i, str.length)}${str.slice(0, i)}`
);

console.log(str_arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

My go-to would be to use JavaScripts built-in array methods. You can break a string into an array of single characters using split with no parameters, and put it back together using join with an empty string as a parameter.

```
let word = 'sydney'
function rotate (anyword) {
  let wordarray= anyword.split()
  let chartomove = wordarray.splice(0, 1)[0]
  wordarray.push(chartomove)
  return wordarray.join('')
}
rotate(word) // returns 'ydneys'
```

Comment: Hi Sydney, StackOverflow doesn't like code-only answers. Because you originally provide no explanation of what this code solves, it was flagged and put on a review queue to see if it should be deleted. Please edit your answer and add a comment so someone doesn't delete it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I find using an array for this kind of string manipulation a bit more readable. 
In the function below, we start with splitting the string into an array.
The second step will be using the native `.shit` method which returns the first item in an array (in our case, the first letter) while modifying the Lastly, as we have the first character and the rest of the string we build them into a new array where we spread (`...`) the modified array and adding the first character at the end. The `join('')` method returns a string out of the new array.

```
function firstToLast (str) {
  const split = str.split('');
  const first = split.shift();
  return [...split, first].join('');
}
```

Hopefully it's clear and helps with what you were trying to achieve

Comment: Thanks @leopal, absolutely right. Added some explanations

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```js
var string = 'aeiou'
   i=0 
   while (i < string.length-1) {
      string = string.substr(1) + string.charAt(0);
      console.log(string);
      i++;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this. Calling Recursion - Works for all the Strings.

```js
var InputStr = 'aeiou';
var i = 0;
var word = [];

function callqueue(InputStr, i) 
{
 StringLength = InputStr.length;
 i = i+1;
 if (i <= StringLength)
 {
  firstChar = InputStr.slice(0, 1);
  remainStr = InputStr.substr(1);
  word.push(remainStr+firstChar);
  callqueue(remainStr+firstChar, i);
 }

 return word;
}

output = callqueue(InputStr, i);
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
function strR(str){
for (let i = 0; i < str.length-1; i++) {
    str = str.substr(1)+str.charAt(0);
    console.log(str);
}

strR('aeiou');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not quite clear. Hope the below solution works for you.

```js
function strR(str){
   var a = str.split('');
   a[a.length] = a.shift();
   return a.join('');
}
strR("aeiou")

/* or */

String.prototype.firstToLast = function() {
   var a = this.split('');
   a[a.length] = a.shift();
   return a.join('');
}

"aeiou".firstToLast();
```